# c++ priority-queue ,pop() element, but memory not release

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I use priority-queue from c++ stl library.but when I pop some elements, the memory space of queue not be less.i want memory space will be less immediately when elements are poped.for example, my queue have five elements, when I pop one element.i want queue only use four elements memory space.

Comment: How are you checking memory consumption?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the code you didn't show. Who knows.... But anyway depending on the implementation and your code this may well happen.

Comment: Also see this question, might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143042/shrinking-a-stdpriority-queue

Comment: *but when I pop some elements* -- How much is "some elements"?  If it's a small amount, then the heap manager isn't going to naively return that memory back to the OS (if that's what you're using to determine memory isn't returned) -- that's not how the (default) heap manager works.  If it did that, your application would slow down considerably.

Comment: You should be very specific about what you expect to have happen when you pop an element from a priority queue and how you expect to observe whether or not that expected thing has actually happened or not -- i.e. how you are measuring, observing or debugging?  It's also worth knowing: *why* do you want this?  _"want memory space will be less"_ is not a very clear or specific description of your requirement.

Comment: how can I know memory space usage of a priority-queue when I debug my program with visual studio 2022

Comment: @wwb1 *how can I know memory space usage of a priority-queue* -- But your question states you are using something to determine the memory space.  So what are you using now to do this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do not know what can I use

Comment: @wwb1 -- This is what you said: `the memory space of queue not be less.`. So my question to you is very simple -- How do you know that the memory space is not less?  We need to know what you're using *now* to say to us that the "memory space is not less".

Answer (score 3):

`std::priority_queue` is not a container. It is a container adaptor. A container adaptor wraps another container. By default, `std::priority_queue` wraps `std::vector`. `std::vector` does not release the storage when you pop an element.

There is no standard container that satisfies the requirements of being wrapped by `std::priority_queue` that also releases storage immediately when element is popped. `std::deque` is the other valid choice besides `std::vector` and it practically releases memory every Nth element where N is implementation specific.

In order to achieve your goal, you can implement a custom `SequenceContainer` that provides `RandomAccessIterator` and that behaves in the way that you want (at the cost of the overhead that you must pay to achieve that behaviour). You can then adopt your custom container with `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: OP could however retrieve the underlying container and try to shrink it. If it is `std::vector` they can call `shrink_to_fit()` on it. No guarantee that this does deallocate but at least something.

Comment: @JacobFaib To expand on you comment, you'd need to inherit `std::priority_queue` to get protected access to the underlying container.

Comment: c++ prioriry_queue can use deque replace vector?

Comment: @wwb1 Yes, you can use deque.

Comment: how can I monitor memory space usage amount of priority-queue when I debug with  visual studio 2022?

Comment: is some library implement a custom sequenceContainer can satisfy my requirements?